# How to create links between all turtles except itself?

Tags: netlogo

I want to create links between all turtles who are green. But I dont know how to include that know link shall be created with the turtle itself.

What I got:

```
ask turtles with [ green? = true ] [ create-links-with turtles with [ green? = true ]  ]
```

Error I get:

> A turtle cannot link to itself. error while household 178 running
>   CREATE-LINKS-WITH   called by procedure GREEN   called by procedure GO
>   called by Button 'go'

Answer (score 4):

Just ask to create link with **other** turtles:

```
ask turtles with [ green? ] 
[ 
    create-links-with other turtles with [ green? ]
]
```